# Cascading foreign keys in mariadb, do they activate triggers?

Tags: triggers, mariadb

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.

Does this work in MariaDB?

Comment: So what does the MariaDB manual say about this?

Comment: I didn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/trigger-limitations/), it seems that it doesn't work in MariaDB either:

> The following restrictions apply to [triggers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/triggers/).
>
> - [...]
> - Triggers are not activated by [foreign key](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/) actions.

"Foreign key actions" refers to the action to perform (`RESTRICT`, `CASCADE`, `SET NULL`, `NO ACTION`, `SET DEFAULT`) on the rows in the current table which references deleted or updated rows in the referenced table.

Also see related bugs:

- MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11472
- MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19402